# Overlapping components in Smartedit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have created one paragraph component, which is below another Banner TopContent-Slot component. In this case the paragraph component is hiding behind the TopContent-Slot and not easily accessible.

Suggest me some way where I can make the below component easily accessible and editable in Smartedit.

Comment: How does your page look if you synchronize it and then access it from the storefront ? Is the paragraph component still hiding behind the other Component ?

Comment: In the storefront, there is no issue. Both the components are coming in good shape

Comment: Did you add the paragraph Component in the same slot as the other Component ? If yes I would suggest adding it into another slot

Comment: Both the components have different slots.